# IBAction Play an MP3

Tags: ios, ios5, mp3, ibaction

I have an App that I am making thatis similar to Urbanspoon. I have a picker the spins and it is hooked up to an IBAction for a UIButton. I want a mp3 file to play once the button is pressed. I feel it will give the user more of an experience by doing this.
I imported the     AVFoundationFramework and the    AudioToolBoxFramework and imported their .h into my main .m file

Here is my action.

```
- (IBAction)spinTheSpinner:(id)sender {


if ([sender isSelected]) {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GoldTapButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [sender setSelected:NO];
     }
else {
     [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PurpleTapButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [sender setSelected:YES];}

[picker1 selectRow:(arc4random() % [self pickerView:picker1 numberOfRowsInComponent:0]) inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

}

Do i need to make a separate action for the same button or can i just add a block of code into this same action. I have the mp3 file is my resources folder so its in my project I just cant find where and what to do to make it happen.

Here is my .h as well just for good measure

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)spinTheSpinner:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *picker1Data;



@end
```

also here is the top of my .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Twitter/Twitter.h"
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"
#import"AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"
@interface ViewController ()

{
@private
UIPickerView *picker1;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
```

Any help or suggestion or code would be a huge help in any way. I am running on a bit of a time schedule. THANKS S.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can just add the code into the same `IBAction` method. You re not limited to th amount of code you can run in the method its currently linked to

Comment: No problem, there is not a straight forward code snippet I can give you, but there there is a helpful developer guide here which you should read. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AudioVideoStartingPoint_iOS/_index.html If you have more specific questions please get back to me :)